# convert _map<string,dynmic> to model in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, types

i have the following record comes from API

```
{
success: true
status: 200,
token: "...",
message: "you have logged in"
user: {id:1, first_name: "..", second_name: "..",}
}
```

it is a single record with a type data of _map<string,dynamic>

and here is my model

```
class LoginResponseModel {
  late bool success;
  late int status;
  late String message;
  late Map<String, dynamic> user;
  late String token;

  LoginResponseModel(
      {required this.success,
      required this.status,
      required this.message,
      required this.user,
      required this.token});

  LoginResponseModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json['success'];
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    user = json['user'];
    token = json['token'];
  }
}
```

I need to convert the record that comes from API with the data type of _map<string,dynamic> to the model and here what I have done so

```
  var test1 = response.map((e) => LoginResponseModel.fromjson(e)).toList();
```

error output

```
LoginResponseModael' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'
```

also used

```
var parsedJson = jsonDecode(response);
```

error output

```
type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Comment: By the way did you actually mean "model" instead of "modal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> it is a **single** record with a type data of _map<string,dynamic>

Since it's a single record, you shouldn't call `.map` with `response.map((e)`.

Instead, simply use the `fromJson` directly:

```
final response = LoginResponseModal.fromjson(response);
```

---

Here is a complete runnable snippet to demonstrate:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final response = jsonDecode("""
{
  "success": true,
  "status": 200,
  "token": "...",
  "message": "you have logged in",
  "user": {"id": 1, "first_name": "..", "second_name": ".."}
}

""");
  final loginResponseModal = LoginResponseModal.fromjson(response);
  print(loginResponseModal.message);
}

class LoginResponseModal {
  late bool success;
  late int status;
  late String message;
  late Map<String, dynamic> user;
  late String token;

  LoginResponseModal(
      {required this.success,
      required this.status,
      required this.message,
      required this.user,
      required this.token});

  LoginResponseModal.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json['success'];
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    user = json['user'];
    token = json['token'];
  }
}
```